# Unable to change local value of memory limit in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have change my memory_limit value in my php.ini file.  However, only the master value is changing when I look at the phpinfo.  The local value will not change.  I try adding a .htaccess with the below line:

> php_value memory_limit 1000M;

in the same folder as my php.ini, but in vain.  The local value will not change.  Any idea how of to change the local value of the memory_limit?  I am using php 5.3.8.  The local value would remain at 128M while the master value is at 1000M.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'local value' or 'master value', but there are two php.ini files, one for apache and one for the cli. Have you changed them both?

Comment: Make sure you did change correct php.ini file. `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` will show you the file path

Comment: if you are working locally then change in to your original `php.ini` file. then you need to restart your server. otherwise changes will not reflect.

Comment: @vascowhite:  I am not sure what you mean by cli.  I have change the php,ini shown in my phpinfo.

Comment: @hmd:  I have checked the php,ini file using phpinfo.

Comment: @Anant:  I did restart the server.

Comment: Why are you putting `.htaccess` in the same folder as your `php.ini`? The `.htaccess` should be in the web root (or a sub folder of it), the `php.ini` goes somewhere like `/etc/php.ini` or another configuration folder, not in the web root.

Comment: Also, are you using cpanel? vhosts? Can we see the vhost config for that domain?

Comment: @LeonardChallis:  Excuse me for my lack of knowledge, but where do I put the .htaccess file?

Comment: `.htaccess` needs to go in your web root. Usually at the top level, where your `index.php` lives. Also, for `php_value` to work, your apache configuration needs to have `AlowOverrides Options` (or `AllowOverrides All`) in it, otherwise this won't work.

Comment: @LeonardChallis:  I tried putting the .htaccess in the same folder as the index.php, however, this prevents my page from loading.  Also, I have just checked my httpd.conf and I don't have any AllowOverrides value there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109030/discussion-between-leonardchallis-and-tabby).